# In a worksheet, through VBA, i want to read a value of a cell and use that value and color cell in another worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Sample()

    Dim wsDiff As Worksheet, wsSheet As Worksheet, wsColorIndex As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, j As Integer      

    Dim delentrysheet As String
    Dim delentrycell As String        

    Dim delentrycolindex As Integer

    Set wsDiff = Sheets("Differences")
    Set wsColorIndex = Sheets("VERSION LOG")
    lRow = wsDiff.Range("E" & wsDiff.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    delentrycolindex = wsColorIndex.Range("I3").Interior.ColorIndex
    For i = 2 To lRow
        If wsDiff.Range("E" & i).Value = "Entered Value Deleted." Then
           delentrysheet = wsDiff.Range("A" & i).Value
           delentrycell = wsDiff.Range("B" & i)
           Set wsSheet = Sheets(delentrysheet)
           With wsSheet
           .Range(delentrycell).Interior.ColorIndex = delentrycolindex
           End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I get an error upon running this program.

> "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Which line is highlighted when it fails?

Comment: the last line of code (.Range(delentrycell).Interior.ColorIndex = delentrycolindex)

Comment: When it fails, what is the value of `delentrycell` ?  Try adding a line `Debug.Print delentrycell` just before the line that fails - you can see the output in the Immediate pane in the VB Editor.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for drilling down the error. When i added Debug.Print delentrycell, it popped up a value "B5 (deleted cell)", which can't be used in method Range. The code works fine upon deleting such entries. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You might check that the delentrysheet exists before you assign it.

I use a function for this:

```
Public function WorksheetExists(byval strSheet as string) as Boolean

Dim wksCurr as excel.worksheet

WorksheetExists = false
For each wksCurr in thisworkbook.worksheets
    If wksCurr.name = strSheet then
        WorksheetExists = true
            Exit for
    End if
Next wksCurr
End function
```

In your code, check:

If worksheetexists(delentrysheet) then
Set xxxx
Else
End if

With some code to handle exceptions, maybe a messagebox

Comment: Hi Art Walls, Thanks for the input. The sheet does exist. I surely can incorporate your code as an additional evaluation method. The error is more specific to last line of code " .Range(delentrycell).Interior.ColorIndex = delentrycolindex". Don't know what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `delentrycell` value with **(row, column)** and try the following.

Instead of using the following code:

```
    .Range(delentrycell).Interior.ColorIndex = delentrycolindex
```

Try using the following code:

```
    .Cells(1,1).Interior.ColorIndex = delentrycolindex
```

You can replace your `Cells(row,column)` with `Cells(delentrycell)` if `delentrycell` properly denotes `(Row,Column)`.